# Quotient of Punctured Disc

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, quotient-spaces

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<1\}$. So $D$ is a punctured disc. If I put the group action generated by $z\mapsto ze^{2\pi i/n}$, then consider the quotient. As at every point, there is an invariant neighbourhood around it, we ge get a Riemann surface. For different $n$, do we get different Reimann surface or not? I think the answer is that they are the same, as we take the holomorphic map between the one given by $n_1$ and $n_2$ by doing scaling along the angle, and this map should be biholomorphic. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "scaling along the angle"?

Comment: @LukasGeyer As for a fixed $n$ and $n'$, they can be considered as an angle from $0-2\pi i/n$, I map angle $\theta$ to angle $\theta/n*n'$.

Comment: That map (multiplying the angle by something) would not be conformal (holomorphic), so it would not help here.

Comment: @LukasGeyer You are correct. Thank you. So are they biholomorphic or not?

Comment: Hint: Can you think of a holomorphic map which multiplies the angle by $n$?

Comment: @LukasGeyer I think $z\mapsto z^n$ can do the job, and the inverse is also holomorphic in the range of interest.

Comment: @LukasGeyer So I think for general $n$ and $n'$, I can use $z\mapsto z^{n'/n}$ to do the job.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go :)